# Azure TimerTrigger functions not running and giving 404 when testing

Tags: azure-functions

I have several Azure C# functions all with TimerTriggers and some of them won't run. When I try them in the Test section the bad ones give 404s.

Here's one that works

```
[FunctionName("formsTimer")]
public static async Task FormJob([TimerTrigger("*/15 * * * *", RunOnStartup = false)] TimerInfo timerInfo, ILogger log)
{
```

and one that doesn't (in a different class)

```
[FunctionName("tableTimer")]
public static async Task TableJob([TimerTrigger("*/30 * * * *", RunOnStartup = false)] TimerInfo timerInfo, ILogger log)
```

When I look in Kudo the function.json files both look fine.

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator-4.0.1",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "runOnStartup": false,
      "schedule": "*/15 * * * *",
      "useMonitor": true,
      "name": "timerInfo"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../bin/TimerFunctions.dll",
  "entryPoint": "TimerFunctions.Functions.Class1.FormJob"
}

{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator-4.0.1",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "runOnStartup": false,
      "schedule": "*/30 * * * *",
      "useMonitor": true,
      "name": "timerInfo"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../bin/TimerFunctions.dll",
  "entryPoint": "TimerFunctions.Functions.Class2.TableJob"
}
```

There are no logs for the functions that don't work.

When I look at the browser network tab the 404 is for this url:

```
"path": "/admin/functions/tableTimer",
```

Why would some functions, which appear identical not work in Azure? Everything runs fine locally.

Answer (score 0):

I think the moral of the story is to supply all six numbers including seconds.
TimerTrigger("0 */30 * * * *) seems to work all the time.

TimerTrigger("*/30 * * * *) seems sporadic in Azure, although it works fine locally.

Also, things work best if they fit into 24 hours. Every 15 hours seems unreliable so I stick to 6, 12 etc.

There's a cheat sheet here.

https://arminreiter.com/2017/02/azure-functions-time-trigger-cron-cheat-sheet/